# calculating mean gray level

Tags: matlab, variables, image-processing

I have a lot of images in `IM{}`. I want to calculate mean graylevel of non-black pixels. When I run my code `sum` has 255 as a maximum value. I don't understand the reason. Why doesn't sum get higher values?

```
for i=1: length(IM)
[L,W,z]=size( IM{i});
k=1;
sum=0;
for L=1:L
    for W=1: W
        if IM{i}(L,W)~=0;
      sum=IM{i}(L,W)+sum;
      k=k+1;
        end
    end    
end
Mean(i)=sum/k
```

end

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's probably because `IM` is of type [`uint8`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/uint8.html). This data type can't hold values larger than 255. Example:

```
>> uint8(200) + uint8(200)
ans =
  255
```

To avoid this, you should convert `IM` to [`double`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/double.html):

```
IM = double(IM);
```

Anyway, your code could be reduced to a single line (including the conversion):

```
result = mean(double(IM(IM>0)));
```

With this approach, you could even dispense with `double`, because [`mean`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/mean.html) (actually [`sum`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/sum.html), which is called by `mean`) converts to `double` automatically:

```
result = mean(IM(IM>0));
```

Comment: In the Image Processing Toolbox you have `rgb2gray` available.